# nodejs webserver : Handling multiple request to same api

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, concurrency, webserver

Does node server cant initiate another request to same api end-point, whose response has not been send yet.
i am doing a big file read operation asynchronously on /something

```
fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'bigFile.txt'), (err, data) => {
    console.log('read Ended!');
    process.send(data.length);
  })
```

when i hit /something on two different tag, i saw that second request only initiates once first request finished.
I would have understood if it fs.readFileSync as it is synchrounous.

Also i dont want to implement child_process as of now

What i am missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded, meaning it can only do one thing at time. You can init multiple express apps. In general, Node is not good for processing great amounts of data or whatever blocks the thread.

Comment: yes...but app using it for backend for some extend...but my confusion is how it handles multiple request to same api at the same time